# How to push a new element to nested array react hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I Am trying to push a new element to my nested array but the issue I am facing is It is creating new array every time, I know this is very silly but I tried to google but not got the answer.

**What i am doing**

- Below is my state

  ```
   const [state, setState] = useState([
     {
       name: "test",
       lname: "lname",
       ages: [
         {
           age: 30
         }
       ]
     }
   ]);
  ```
- What I am trying to do on click is

  ```
   const randomAge = () => {
     let rg = ((Math.random() * 1000) / 10).toFixed();
     setState({ ...state, ages: { ...state.ages, age: rg } });
   };
  ```

But it is returning very wrong output, shown as below

```
{
  "0": {
    "name": "test",
    "lname": "lname",
    "ages": [
      {
        "age": 30
      }
    ]
  },
  "ages": {
    "rg": "34"
  }
}
```

Output I want is like below

```
[
  {
    "name": "test",
    "lname": "lname",
    "ages": [
      {
        "age": 30
      },
      {
        "age": 50
      },
      {
        "age": 60
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I know I am doing a very silly mistake somewhere, but right now I am not abe to find

**I am just trying to push a new random age to my ages array on click of button**

[Code sandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/spring-tree-vypmzw?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current code is mutating the state invariant from arrays to objects.

> ```
> const randomAge = () => {
>   let rg = ((Math.random() * 1000) / 10).toFixed();
>   setState({ ...state, ages: { ...state.ages, age: rg } });
> };
> ```

If the `state` array only ever has a single element in it then use a functional state update and create a new array reference with only the single object element in it. Shallow copy the previous state's `state[0]` element and update the `ages` property by *also* shallow copying the array and appending the new object with the `age` property.

Example:

```
const randomAge = () => {
  const age = (Math.random() * 100).toFixed();
  setState((prev) => [
    {
      ...prev[0],
      ages: [...prev[0].ages, { age }]
    }
  ]);
};
```

[image: Edit how-to-push-a-new-element-to-nested-array-react-hooks]

If you are eventually wanting to handle multiple object elements in the `state` array then I suggest adding a GUID to each object and pass this to the `randomAge` callback so it can correctly update the correct state.

Example:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { nanoid } from "nanoid";

export default function App() {
  const [state, setState] = useState([
    {
      id: nanoid(),
      name: "test1",
      lname: "lname1",
      ages: []
    },
    {
      id: nanoid(),
      name: "test2",
      lname: "lname2",
      ages: []
    }
  ]);

  const randomAge = (id) => () => {
    const age = (Math.random() * 100).toFixed();
    setState((prev) =>
      prev.map((el) =>
        el.id === id
          ? {
              ...el,
              ages: el.ages.concat({ age })
            }
          : el
      )
    );
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {state.map((li, ind) => {
        return (
          <React.Fragment key={li.id}>
            <div>{li.name}</div>
            <div>{li.lname}</div>
            <br />
            {li.ages.map((d) => <div>{d.age}</div>)}
            <button onClick={randomAge(li.id)}>Add random age</button>
          </React.Fragment>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit how-to-push-a-new-element-to-nested-array-react-hooks (forked)]

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, I was looking to do this way only, thanx for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Couple things of note:

- `.ToFixed()` returns a string and not a number type
- You want your setState to look like `{ ...state, ages: [ ...state.ages, {age: rg} ] }` this is because ages is an array, and so you need to use the spread operator with the array syntax

Edit:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-jkgjf4?file=src/App.js

Working stackblitz, in a nutshell your object is an array so we need to treat it as such and loop over it as we are creating a new object. This way it is easier to update it than trying to use spread operators as it can quickly get very ugly.

```
const [state, updateState] = useState([
{
  name: 'test',
  lname: 'lname',
  ages: [
    {
      age: 30,
    },
  ],
},
]);

 function update() {
//turning it into an int
let rg = Number.parseInt(((Math.random() * 1000) / 10).toFixed());

let newState = [...state];
newState.forEach((x) => x.ages.push({ age: rg }));

console.log('new State: ', newState);
updateState(newState);
}
```

Comment: This did not worked, I have shared my code sand box please check once

Comment: @viveksingh i updated my answer with a stackblitz example

Comment: please don't introduce the pitfall of assigning newState = [...state]
if state needs to be updated and the previous version of state is relevant, you are required to use prevState of setState(prevstate=> ...)

Comment: He did not specify how his state needs to be or anything of that sort, just that he wanted it to output a specific format. That's what the answer does, it is a minimal working example for what he needs and maintains immutability since we never touch the original state directly.

Comment: I will let him expand further on this to make sure he filters out the correct user this needs to be applied to. The idea that a user has an array of ages also makes no sense conceptually. You have 1 age, not multiple ages

Comment: The OP ***did*** specify how they want the state to be, right in their post. This answer mutates the state. Mutating state in React is anti-pattern and leads to rendering issues. What the OP *didn't* specify is what the `ages` array represents, so who's to say there can't be more than 1 of them?

Comment: As far as I see he said he just wanted to push random arrays. React isn’t my forte, but I don’t see any mutation of the state here directly. We are setting a new object to represent our state, we are not actively mutating the current state. At least that is how I would do it in the 200+ reducers I have in my angular project which isn’t that far off from how redux with react does it

Comment: You can see what OP originally declared the state as, and they also specifically mention *"Output I want is like below"` and provide an example expected result. `newState.forEach((x) => x.ages.push({ age: rg }));` directly pushes into the `ages` array which is still a reference into the previous state. In React we necessarily need to create new array and object references for any state, and nested state, that is being updated.

Comment: Would there still be a reference even though we’ve applied the spread operator to newState as […state]? That should create a new object,  no?

Comment: That is a "copy by reference". `let newState = [...state];` creates a new array reference, but each element is reference back to the original array.

Comment: I see, I guess my original understanding wasn’t fully correct

Answer (score 0):

Your initial setState() should be an object not an array.

```
const [state, setState] = useState(
  {
    name: "test",
    lname: "lname",
    ages: [
      {
        age: 30
      }
    ]
  }
);
```

As per the function **randomAge** try the following

```
const randomAge = () => {
 let rg = ((Math.random() * 1000) / 10).toFixed();
     setState({ 
      ...state,
        ages: [ 
          ...state.ages,
          {
            age : rg
          }
        ] 
      });
    };
```

You'll see that ages within the state object has been changed to an Array. With the spread operator you're copying the previous state ages array into it. This should be smaller objects from your code and lastly you're creating another object with **age : rg** as the only pair value.

It might be better to keep ages as an array and simply push the **rg** value into it instead of creating objects. Unless you're adding multiple KEY:VALUE pairs.

Comment: Hey that state should be like [] array only because in the future I might need to add a new `name` and `last name`, That is why I have to use array. please check my codesand box link

Answer (score 0):

Just change your randomAge function like this.

```
  const randomAge = () => {
    const rg = ((Math.random() * 1000) / 10).toFixed();
    const newAgesArray = state[0].ages;
    newAgesArray.push({ age: rg });
    setState([...state, { ages: newAgesArray }]);
  };
```

Considering only one item in the whole array, I used an index **0**.

Also `const newAgesArray = state[0].ages` doesn't make a whole new copy of the array, it just creates a reference. It works but it's not ideal when working with state. I recommend you to do some shallow or deep copy instead - **DYOR**.

Answer (score -1):

i am not sure but, you use array in start state
  `ages: [ {age: 30} ]`
but in setState `setState({ ...state, ages: { ...state.ages, age: rg } });` you use a object instead of Array

Comment: This should probably be a comment instead of an answer. Make sure that any answers you post are actual attempts to solve the question.